# Custom php.ini file in when executing 'php' as a shell script

Tags: php

I'm running `php` as a shell script.

(I am not sure if "shell script" is correct. The file starts with `#!/usr/bin/php`.)

This works great. But the MongoDB class doesn't get loaded as the correct *php.ini* file (having `extension=mongo.so`) is not used.

How do I make it use *that* *php.ini* file?

I already tried `#!/usr/bin/php -c /usr/local/lib/php.ini`

But I still get the same error - `Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found`

What can be done?

Comment: Please specify your server OS. (and if ubuntu, check if /etc/php5/cli/php.ini exists - that's the one to edit)

Comment: The output of `php -i` on the command line (basically doing a phpinfo() call) will list exactly what extensions are loaded, where PHP is looking for them, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular situation. I would

- Check to see if the Mongo module is loaded (using [extension_loaded()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php) or [class_exists()](https://www.php.net/class_exists))
- If not loaded, try to load the Mongo module using [dl()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php)
- If loading fails, display an error message so the admin can take care of it ([STDERR](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) or [trigger_error()](https://www.php.net/trigger_error)

Most distributions already ship different versions of php.ini for Web Servers and CLI. Are there other reasons to add another php.ini configuration for script XYZ (in addition to normal configuration)?

Comment: Using `extension_loaded()` and then `dl()` did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try putting php.ini in the same folder as the php binary. It seems to look there first.

I know this because I used a very powerful and useful command-line program called **strace** to show me what's really going on behind my back

```
$ strace -o strace.log php --version
$ grep php.ini strace.log
```

Strace digs out kernel (system) calls that your program makes and dumps the output into the file specified after -o

It's easy to use **grep** to search for occurrences of php.ini in this log. It's pretty obvious looking at the following typical response to see what is going on.

```
open("/usr/bin/php.ini", O_RDONLY)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/php.ini", O_RDONLY)          = 3
lstat("/etc/php.ini", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=69105, ...}) = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Edit .bashrc located at your home directory and add this line:

```
alias php='php -c /path-to-custom/php.ini'
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across this, because I had the same problem.  Problem is there is more than one *php.ini* file used.
The one used by Apache is located in

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

This is the one that is modified to run MongoDB with *extension=mongo.so*.

However, when running a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job, or from the terminal, it loads a different ini file.  You can find this by using the line

```
grep php.ini strace.log
```

It is [mentioned by thomas-peter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578904/custom-php-ini-file-in-when-executing-php-as-a-shell-script/4578919#4578919).

The path where it displays '=3' is the *php.ini* file loaded when running the engine from the terminal, this ini file will need "extension=mongo.so" placed in it as well.

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to use a small `sh` wrapper, something like this below in a *myapp.sh* file. Don’t forget to `chmod +x` on the script to run it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

SOMEVAR='Yea Baby!'

export SOMEVAR

php -c /path/to/my/custom/php.ini /path/to/my/old_script.php
```

With the added bonus of being able to set or override environment variables pre-run.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a gotcha with PHP.

`php -c /path/to/my/custom/php.ini` works from the command line.

But try it in a script like this `#!/usr/local/bin/php -c /path/to/my/custom/php.ini` and your custom php won't load.

**The Solution**

Get rid of the space between `-c` and your path:

`#!/usr/local/bin/php -c/path/to/my/custom/php.ini`