# executing php script on console

Tags: php, linux, bash, mongodb

I have a php script, and I am trying to run it on my linux console. I can run it with curl and on any browser wtihout any errors. This is the error I am getting.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mongo' not found in .....

Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found in ....
```

I have no idea why I am getting this error, thank you

Comment: With what you have given me, i would assume that Class 'Mongo' can not be found

Comment: You need to install the driver

Comment: Mongo is out  hunting buffalo at the moment, but if you leave a message ...

Comment: what command are you using to run the script on console?

Comment: You should add extension=mongo.so to your /etc/php5/cli/php.ini file

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578904/custom-php-ini-in-when-executing-php-as-shell-script

Comment: I don't think you guys read it, I said, It is okay I don't get any errors If I execute it with curl or on my browser, mongo is already in my php.ini and it is already installed. This is weird, I only get it If I execute it on my console.

Comment: cli uses a different php.ini than via Apache

Comment: @rootkit007 I use php filename.php

Answer (score 3):

You should add `extension=mongo.so` to your `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` file

You can run following command to identify which ini file your php version using:

```
vps01:/usr/share/php# php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
```

Comment: this one solved the problem :) I did not know apache and client uses different drivers :) thank you

Comment: @Satish You "should" should you? What about the more detailed answer below? You put an answer that any of us could have, you didn't even explain why it works...for all we know you don't actually know why it works you just plucked the info from the comments above....

Comment: In rush of get first answer! I made it short.. my bad :(

Comment: Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Comment: Just after the answer, i saw green answer flag in my answer and suddenly it disappear :(

Comment: Lol the OP is a indecisive one

Answer (score 2):

It happens because php uses different configurations for web-server and CLI. Often the CLI config is placed in `/etc/php5/cli/`. Compare it with your general php.ini file and you will find what causes the error.

Comment: thank you :) now I know apache and client uses different drivers :)